# How can I fix the 11, 12, and 13 to end with "th"

Tags: python

The code will type out a statement then will enter a number that rises by 1 every loop and will put "st of all", "nd of all", "rd of all", or "th of all" depending on the ending of the number. **When it gets to 11, 12, and 13 it just uses "st of all", "nd of all", and "rd of all" when it should just use "th of all" for 11, 12, and 13. **

```
import pyautogui
import time

time.sleep(5)

number = 0
numberSuffix = ""

while True:

    number += 1

    if str(number).endswith("1"):
        numberSuffix = "st of all"
    if str(number).endswith("2"):
        numberSuffix = "nd of all"
    if str(number).endswith("3"):
        numberSuffix = "rd of all"
    if str(number).endswith("4" or "5" or "6" or "7" or "8" or "9" or "0" or "11" or "12" or "13"):
        numberSuffix = "th of all"

    print(str(number) + numberSuffix)

    pyautogui.typewrite("Statement")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    pyautogui.press("enter")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    pyautogui.typewrite(str(number) + numberSuffix)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    pyautogui.press("enter")
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: Is there a specific issue? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

Just add special cases:

```py
def get_ending(num):
    if num in [11, 12, 13]:
        return "th"
    lastdig = num % 10
    if lastdig == 1:
        return "st"
    elif lastdig == 2:
        return "nd"
    elif lastdig == 3:
        return "rd"
    else:
        return "th"

# more code...
while True:
    number += 1
    numberSuffix = get_ending(number) + " of all"
    print(str(number) + numberSuffix)
```

Answer (score 0):

its because your if statement for 11,12,13 is the last one, try having the last if statement the first if statement (above the current if statement) and see what happens, there might be some other edge cases after you change that, but it would give you and idea of what you are doing wrong

```
if str(number).endswith("4" or "5" or "6" or "7" or "8" or "9" or "0" or "11" or "12" or "13"):
    numberSuffix = "th of all"
elif str(number).endswith("1"):
    numberSuffix = "st of all"
elif str(number).endswith("2"):
    numberSuffix = "nd of all"
elif str(number).endswith("3"):
    numberSuffix = "rd of all"
```

I would recommend making a def for this at least

Answer (score 0):

This line doesn't do what you want it to do:

```
 if str(number).endswith("4" or "5" or "6" or "7" or "8" or "9" or "0" or "11" or "12" or "13"):
```

What's happening here is `"4" or "5" or "6" or ...` just gets evaluated to `"4"`. Go ahead, try it yourself. What you'd actually need to do here would be more like:

```
if str(number).endswith("4") or str(number).endswith("5") or ...
```

That's obviously a lot of extra stuff to type out. It's probably a lot easier to do what @Aplet123 suggested and check the actual numbers instead of the string conversion of the number.

```
last_digit = number % 10
last_two_digits = number % 100
if 10 < last_two_digits < 14
    numberSuffix = "th of all"
elif last_digit == 1:
    numberSuffix = "st of all"
elif last_digit == 2:
    numberSuffix = "nd of all"
elif last_digit == 3:
    numberSuffix = "rd of all"
else:
    numberSuffix = "th of all"
```

Comment: This helped me see the issue and learn from it. Thanks!